# Conditioning formula for event with Probability Zero

Tags: probability-theory

Recall that for events $A,B$ and $C$ with $P(C)>0$,
$$
P(A \cap B \mid C) = P(A \mid B \cap C)\cdot P(B \mid C).
$$

I'd like to show an analogous result when $P(C) = 0$ but am having trouble.  The context is $C = \{X = x\}$ for a continuous random variable $X$.  I'm familiar with regular conditional probabilities, but I can't seem to apply them correctly here (what is $P(A \mid \{X = x\}, B)$ in terms of regular conditional probabilities?)

To be clear, I'm trying to prove
$$
P(A \cap B \mid \{X = x\}) = P(A \mid B \cap \{X = x\})\cdot P(B \mid \{X = x\}).
$$

Comment: It might help to explain how you define P(A|B,X=x) when (X=x) has probability zero.

Comment: To focus on the last line, your whole "probability world" has been restricted to the cases $X=x$.  Do you have probability distributions for $A,B$ in this restricted circumstance?

Comment: Follow @Did's lead. Take limits.