# Compute the distribution of a conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent Gaussian random variables and $Z = X +Y$. Then we know that $X$ and $Z$ are jointly Gaussian and $P(X=x \vert Z=z)$ is also Gaussian. Is there any simple way to show this? I know one way that we use $P(X=x \vert Z=z) = \dfrac{P(X=x, Z=z)}{Z=z}$ and write the explicit pdfs. Then we show the result has the form of Gaussian. Can we show this somehow using properties of jointly Gaussian variables?

Now, consider a Bernoulli random variable $W$ which is independent of $X$ and $Y$. Now we want to compute the distribution of $P(X=x \vert Z=z, W=w, WZ = q)$. Is this one also Gaussian?

My approach:
If $wz =q$, then
\begin{align}
P(X=x \vert Z=z, W=w, WZ = q) = P(X=x \vert Z=z, W=w) = P(X=x \vert Z=z)
\end{align}
where the last equality is true because $W$ is independent of $X,Y$. Hence, the distribution is Gaussian.

But, what if $wz \neq q$?

Comment: Given $Z=z$ and $W=w$, the question is meaningless  if $WZ \not =wz$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $wz\ne q$, then you are conditioning on the impossible event, and this was aleady addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541901/is-it-that-pa-mid-emptyset-1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110112/probability-conditional-on-a-zero-probability-event)

Comment: I updated the question, can you take a look at the first question?

Comment: Other than plugging in the formula, I don't know of any way to prove that the conditional of a multivariate Gaussian is Gaussian. The only thing I can think about is to simplify the computation using matrices, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)

Comment: Okay, Is the fact that "the conditional of a multivariate Gaussian is Gaussian" a theorem? any reference? Assume we know this, how can we use this to conclude that $P(X=x | Z=z)$ is Gaussian?

Comment: In the section "Conditional distributions" of the link I provided, wikipedia not only state this, but also gives you a formula for the mean and variance (both in matrix form and explicit form for bivariate case)

Comment: Yes, I found that there. Using that we can say that $P(X=x | Y=y, X=x)$ is Gaussian. How to get the result we want form there? Using the fact that linear function of a multivariate Gaussian is Gaussian?

Comment: Then your multivariate should be $(X,Y,X)$, which is a degenerate multivariate normal, so the formula in the link does not apply.